# Speeding up a video with audio

Tags: video

I am trying to speed up an MP4 video (and save it)! I tried different tools (including openshot, ffmpeg), but the problem is that the video is played at a faster speed, but the audio is gone! 
Does anybody know how I can do that in Ubuntu? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to speed up the audio too, or only the video?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!